# Some questions regarding SSH key authentication

Tags: ssh

As the title says, I have some questions regarding SSH key authentication method on a Linux machine.

First of all, I generated my keys on my PC and added the public key in the authorized_keys file, and everywhing is working fine but I still don't know very well how this works.

- I can only login to the root user with my key though SSH, and I would like to login to different users. Those users are missing some permissions or my key is attached to the root user?
- If more than a person will have access to the machine using different keys, will they have access to all users, for example, the root user?
- Like I said before, I'm working with different users, is there anyway that I can add keys to only a certain user? For example, I create the user 'john', tell my friend John to 
  create the keys on his computer, and then add the key to the authorized keys but that he can only log in to the user 'john' when using his key.

I have searched for hours trying to find some info about this but couldn't find some answer, I'm sorry if this has been answered before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public key authentication is typically per user. Each user should have a different /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys file, which grants access to only that user.

Users who don't have that file can only log in using their password.

Said that, once you log in as root you can then execute "su anotheruser" to act on behalf of that user. Only root can do this, of course.

Alternatively, you can set up system-wide key trust if you have 2 servers with the same users.  This is done with the file /etc/hosts.equiv

And another trick is to have all users in a server with the same version of "authorized_keys" file, so you can log in as any user with the same private key.

Answer (score 1):

The `authorized_keys` file is per-user. When you add a public key to the root user's `authorized_keys` file, then the remote account with the corresponding private key can log in to the root account. Your bullet  points in order:

- You must add your public key to the `authorized_keys` file of each user you wish to log in to using keys.
- Each additional remote person's public key will only have permissions to log in to the account(s) you add their public key to. So, if you add John's key to only the `authorized_keys` file for user 'sam', then John will be able to log in to the 'sam' account and no others.
- Yes - as I said, add the remote person's key(s) to only the account you want them to log in to.